# Java application: detect whether launched from mounted dmg

Tags: java, macos, filesystems

How a Java application can detect on macOS that it was launched from a mounted dmg (instead of from a writable file system - even if writable means admin rights would be required)?

Comment: What's the down-vote for? What's a mounted *dmg*? Ah, a .dmg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is launched from a path starting with `/private/var/folders/` and contains `/AppTranslocation/`, so checking for this should be a reasonable way to detect for launching from a mounted dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue, there is no way a java application can reach across anything beyond the stuff, the file system presents to it under its present privileges. The file system won't tell it that it's a mounted dmg, a ssd or a network drive.

If you only want to find out, if the part of the file system, the app is launched in (`System.getProperty("user.dir")`) is writable, you could just try to create an empty file.

If you want to find out, if it would be writable, if it would run under elevated privileges, again, you can't.